# a href new tab open

Tags: html, anchor, href

I want to open a new tab without show that tab immediately

But i do not want use the following attributes in  tag

1. _blank
2. _top
3. _parent
4. _self

So without these attributes how to implement.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the standard means for achieving your goal?

Comment: Not that those are attributes, they are values accepted by the `target` attribute.

Comment: @quetin, they might be tried the standard attributes, that why angli mentioned the all attributes. he may wants to some otherway in his project or something

Comment: if it's only for you,, see your browser Tab settings for an option whether new tab should be open in background - hold down `Ctrl` for default opening tabs or `Shift+Ctrl` for the opposite behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not a link opens in a new tab is down to the user and their browser settings.

To do it without HTML attributes, you'd have to use JavaScript.